# Laravel hasmany relation object

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i got some question about the Eloquent

i have an album contains many photo, and each of those photo has tags.

my model look like

```
class Album extends Eloquent {
    public function photo() {
       return $this->hasMany('Photo','album_id')->select('url_thumb', 'url_natual',      'url_thumb_tiny');
    }
}

  class Photo extends Eloquent {
      public function tags() {
        return $this->hasMany('PhotoTags','photo_id')->select(array('x', 'y','width','height','msg'));
      }
  }

class PhotoTags extends Eloquent {
    public function photo() {
      return $this->belongsTo('Photo','photo_id');
    }
}
```

My controller looks like

```
   class AlbumController extends Controller {
      protected $data = [];

      public function __construct() {
         $this->data['item'] = Album::where('album_id', '=', $id)- >where('user_id','=',Auth::user()->user_id)->first();
      }

      public function managePhoto($id) {
        print_r($this->data['item']->photo[0]);                 //it's works fine, i can get photos under the album
        print_r($this->data['item']->photo[0]->tags);    //i can't get tags of each photo
     }
 }
```

how can i get tags of each photo???

Comment: u can use eager loading ,so in the controller u use `Photo::with('tags)->get()` and loop over them in the view ,now each item will be fetched along with its tag ,check http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ohh.... i've figure it out

it's because Album model
i've miss select photo_id

so i change the code of model as below , and it's work.

```
class Album extends Eloquent {
   public function photo() {
      return $this->hasMany('Photo','album_id')->select('photo_id','url_thumb', 'url_natual',      'url_thumb_tiny');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all the tags of each photo you will have to loop over the collection of photos.

```
$photos = $this->data['item']->photo;
$tags = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
foreach($photos as $photo){
    $tags = $tags->merge($photo->tags);
}
```

In this example I'm using an Eloquent Collection since the result ($photo->tags) is a collection too. You could also use an array if you're more comfortable with that.

And also don't forget to [eager load](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading) your relations, otherwise the db will be queried for every model in the collection.

```
Album::where('album_id', '=', $id)
     ->where('user_id','=',Auth::user()->user_id)
     ->with('tags')
     ->first();
```